# VoiceOver Cursor vs Keyboard Focus

Tags: reactjs, keyboard, accessibility, voiceover

[image: Seems to skip over keyboard focus when using VoiceOver navigation]

While navigating with VoiceOver, my keyboard focus seems to skip right over the Save to a portfolio button.

Both the keyboard navigation and the VoiceOver cursor follow to the other buttons, however, when I try to navigate to the Save to a portfolio button, the keyboard focus (blue highlight) will not follow and I cannot select it or click it as a link. Does anyone have any idea why or what I need to do to remedy this?

Save to a portfolio code:

```js
const DropDown = ({ sxStyle, sxTiny, buttonLabel, options }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const toggleStyle = sxTiny ? sxStyle.tiny : sxStyle.toggle
  const wrapperStyle = sxTiny ? sxStyle.tinyWrapper : sxStyle.wrapper

  return (
    <div
      className='wrapper'
      sx={wrapperStyle}
      role='button'
      onBlur={(event) => {
        if (!event.currentTarget.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
          setOpen(false)
        }
      }}
    >
      <Button
        variant='primary'
        className='dropdown-toggle'
        aria-label='Add to Portfolio'
        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        sx={toggleStyle}
      >
        { buttonLabel }
      </Button>
      <div
        role='listbox'
        sx={open ? sxStyle.optionsOpen : sxStyle.optionsClosed}>
        { options }
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that disabled buttons are not included in the tab sequence. There are many other reasons buttons can be excluded from the tab sequence as well, usually involving non-semantic markup. You would need to include your markup before that possibility could be assessed.

Comment: I added the DropDown component code. Do you need to see the code for the button in 'theme-ui'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to replace your

```
<div role=button>
```

with a semantically correct

```
<button type="button">
```

If that is not possible, you could add an attribute of tabindex="0", but the button will not activate with the spacebar as it should unless you add a keydown listener and handler.